# Skipping columns with certain values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to write `for` loop to solve the following equation on a `data.frame`:

```
a <- matrix(runif(n = 2151, 0, 0.5), nrow = 2151, ncol = 44) # matrix with certain values from 0.0 to 0.5
a <- data.frame(a) # save to data.frame
b <- runif(n = 2151, 0.9, 1) # generate values from 0.9 to 1 
a[ ,2] <- b # introducing higher values to data.frame

mean_error = numeric(0)
for(i in seq(1, length(a), 2)){ # iterate over 1st,3rd etc. column 
  if(a[[i]] < 0.9) { # skip the column if values are above value
    mean_err = mean(100 * abs(a[[i]] - a[[i + 1]] / mean(a[[i]] + a[[i + 1]]))) # calculate mean error of column
    mean_error = append(mean_error, mean_err) # save results
  }
}
```

It simply provides me the mean error of the first 2 columns and iterates further giving 21 values. I would like to make this loop more sensitive to changes in column values and make it skip the second column while iterating through `data.frame` that have higher values (above 1). Obviously, it does not ommit the second column and produce wrong results. I tried to solve this with  `if(a[[i]] < 0.9)` but it does not work. Also tried to `melt()`-ing of data and iterating through rows, but without much success. I would appreciate any idea to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, so you want to calculate the mean error for ever column while skipping the second row ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to have mean error for 1st and 3rd column. The case is that sometimes not necessarily dataset obtained from my lab work have all columns with values below 0.9 (it depends on aparature calibration period and then columns with higher values are introduced). I would like to have a case sensitive loop.

Comment: I suspect it has a simpler solution. What to with values > 0.9, set as 0 or remove them from the columns ? You want to calculate mean absolute error for only column 1 and 3 or (1 and 3), then(3 and 5) so on ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your use of `runif` so I have created my own version of `a`, I think it represents what you were getting at.

I have provided two options, each gives the result in a different form and each deals with column 2 that you are trying to skip in a different way, hopefully you can get what you want from between the two options.

Create the dummy data:

```
a <- matrix(runif(n = 2000, min = 0, max = 0.5),nrow = 100, ncol = 20) 
a <-  data.frame(a) 
b <- runif(n = 100, min = 0.9, max = 1) 
a[, 2] <- b
```

Option 1: use a `for-loop` to iterate over the columns, producing a `vector` containing the result. Here column 2 is left as 0, this may not be ideal...

```
result <- vector(length = ncol(a))
for (i in 1:ncol(a)) {
  if(all(a[,i] < 0.9) == TRUE) {
  result[i]  <- mean(100 * abs(a[,i] - a[,i] + 1) / mean(a[,i] + a[,i] + 1))
    }
  }

result
```

Option 2: is to use `apply`, this results in a `list` and column 2 which is meant to be skipped returns `NULL`

```
apply(a, 2, function(x) {
  if(all(x < 0.9) == TRUE) {
    res <- mean(100 * abs(x - x + 1) / mean(x + x + 1))
  }
  }
)
```

You could then easily remove all `NULL` values from the result.

Answer (score 0):

@Manish Saraswat your suggestion to remove problematic columns first was the right solution and code provided by @flee helped me a lot. To filter the unwanted columns I used `select()` from `dplyr` package. Then simply removed NULL values from created list with `sapply()`. Further mean error calculations went undisturbed.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- matrix(runif(n = 2151, 0, 0.5), nrow = 2151, ncol = 44) # matrix with values from 0.0 to 0.5
a <- data.frame(a) # save to data.frame
b <- runif(n = 2151, 0.9, 1) # generate values from 0.9 to 1 
a[ ,2] <- b # introducing higher values to data.frame

b=numeric(0) #vector to save results

for (i in 1:length(a)) { # saves the right columns as list and sets rest as NULL
  if(all(a[i] < 0.8) == TRUE){
    b[i] = select(a,names(a[i]))   
  }
}

b[sapply(b, is.null)] <- NULL # removes NULLL from list
```